# Failed to search on AWS Elasticsearch using python elasticsearch returns 411

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query, aws-elasticsearch

I tried to search the data over AWS elasticsearch with python client elasticsearch

I can able to create index, load data. But search is not working.

Please help me out from this problem.

Here is sample code:

```
es.search(index="test_index", size=2, body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
```

Error:

Undecodable raw error response from server: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
TransportError(411, '\n\n\n\nERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved\n\n\n\n

## ERROR

\n

### The requested URL could not be retrieved

\n\n

---

\n\n\n

**Invalid Request** error was encountered while trying to process the request:

\n\n\n

```
GET /test_index/_search?size=2 HTTP/1.1\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 28\r\nx-amz-date: 20180723T114857Z\r\nx-amz-content-sha256: 328683bef5f07407759e09894e2785f4017bcd8914592ce04d87cc45b4d3be35\r\nAuthorization: ** NOT DISPLAYED **\r\nHost: search-testelasticseach-pkpbravqd4djbi3kjtihsra5ma.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com\r\n
```

\n\n\n

Some possible problems are:

\n

  \n
  Missing or unknown request method.
  \n
  Missing URL.
  \n
  Missing HTTP Identifier (HTTP/1.0).
  \n
- Request is too large.
  \n
- Content-Length missing for POST or PUT requests.
  \n
- Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed.
  \n
- HTTP/1.1 Expect: feature is being asked from an HTTP/1.0 software.
  \n

\n\n

Your cache administrator is admin@localhost.

\n
\n\n\n\nif (\'GET\' != \'[unknown method]\') document.getElementById(\'missing-method\').style.display = \'none\';\nif (\'http://search-testelasticseach-pkpbravqd4djbi3kjtihsra5ma.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com/test_index/_search?size=2\' != \'[no URL]\') document.getElementById(\'missing-url\').style.display = \'none\';\nif (\'http\' != \'[unknown protocol]\') document.getElementById(\'missing-protocol\').style.display = \'none\';\n\n\n

---

\n\n

Generated Mon, 23 Jul 2018 11:48:57 GMT by localhost (squid/3.5.23)

\n\n\n\n')

Answer (score 0):

Use `send_get_body_as='POST'` in [Elasticsearch constructor](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/#environment-considerations).